Не могу подключиться к MySQL
При попытке подключения через Adminer выскакивает ошибка

Access denied for user 'grafana'@'172.19.0.4' (using password: YES)

.
Файл docker:
'''
version: '3.0'

services:
db:
   image: mariadb:10.8
   restart: always
   environment:
     MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: p76Se7BoVbrn
     MARIADB_DATABASE: monitoring
     MARIADB_USER: admin
     MARIADB_PASSWORD: NoPasaran1842
   volumes:
    - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

adminer:
   image: adminer:latest
   restart: always
   environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_DB_DRIVER: mysql
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_DB_HOST: db
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_DB_NAME: monitoring
      ADMINER_DESIGN: flat
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

grafana:
   image: grafana/grafana
   ports:
   - '3000:3000'

'''
